# Elasticsearch query to process log data

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an event log of an e-commerce website in `Elasticsearch`. 
Each event is a record in ES

```
{
    "_index": "event_log",
    "_type": "log_type",
    "_id": "3ud-kmoBazYRVz7KCgIy",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "user_id": 123,
      "event": "click",
      "category": "abc",
      "product_id": 1112
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "event_log",
    "_type": "log_type",
    "_id": "4Od-kmoBazYRVz7KCgLr",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "user_id": 123,
      "event": "click",
      "category": "abc",
      "product_id": 1118
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "event_log",
    "_type": "log_type",
    "_id": "4ud-kmoBazYRVz7KkwL2",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "user_id": 123,
      "event": "cart",
      "category": "xyz",
      "product_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "event_log",
    "_type": "log_type",
    "_id": "2ud-kmoBazYRVz7KCALB",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "user_id": 123,
      "event": "cart",
      "category": "xyz",
      "product_id": 11
    }
  },
```

I want list of all the `product_id`s grouping `event`, `category`, `user`.

Expected output:

```
{"click": {
   "abc": {
     "123": {
       "product_id": [1112, 1118]
      }
    }
   },
 "cart": {
   "xyz": {
     "123": {
       "product_id": [1, 11]
      }
    }
   }
  }
```

I will be having millions of records in the index. Querying all the records and processing it is time-consuming. Is there a way to produce the output in a single query? I'm sure it is not possible to generate exactly in the given format. Something near to it is very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi here is my suggestion (first try)

```
GET event_log/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "event": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "event"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "category": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "category"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "product_id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "product_id"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```